# FastAPI: how to access the APIRoute object inside the dependency

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette

I'm using FastAPI where the main app is using `include_router` to add extra routes to the fastAPI app.

I would like to add a generic validation on all the routes.
I found in the documentation that you can achieve this by using the dependencies when including a router.

> https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/#the-main-fastapi

This works and is getting executed by all the http requests.
Thus far everything great!

Now, I want to know inside this generic validation function (being injected using the Depends() in all the routes) what route is invoking the function.

I found a way to get access to the actual request (using fastapi.routing.Request as input parameter for the function) **but I would like to get access to the function or the name of the APIRoute itself**.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from fastapi.routing import Request, APIRoute

async def check_permission(req: Request, route: APIRoute):
    print("test me")

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(admin.service_api, dependencies=[Depends(check_permission)])
```

`RuntimeError: no validator found for <class 'fastapi.routing.APIRoute'>`

Perhaps this is a bad idea all together and should I do it in a different way?
All suggestions are very much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you add some code in to your question? It's kinda hard to help rn.

Comment: Good idea. I added it to the original question. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need the function name or route name? Why not use the `request.url`?

Answer (score 3):

I think I found a workaround (by using the Request object).
Maybe it's not very Pythonic:

```py
async def check_permission(req: Request):
   f = req.scope['endpoint'] 
   # f is the function object of the fast api route endpoint
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually using the Request object is the best practice, since it holds the entire data of the Request, I can not see a reason to not to use it.

Even if you create a workaround for this error, you can not get this work in a proper way. Because the APIRoute is not a valid Pydantic Field type, so our FastAPI should be raising FastAPIError for this.

So the answer is: You should use **Request** object.

Comment: The main reason would be that I want to create internal logic based on the documented operations (see operationId in [OpenAPI standards](https://swagger.io/specification/#operation-object)). This is more explicit than using some string function on a URL. The request object appears to have no single property that I can interpret without first altering it.

Comment: Then there is a better way! see [**Path Operation Advanced Configuration**](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/path-operation-advanced-configuration/)

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how that can solve my issue.
The operation_id is a property of the APIRoute object, to which I don't have access in a Dependency object.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps, it returns `APIRoute` object, can be used inside the dependency. I'm not sure it is the safe way of doing this. `Request` object should be injected beforehand.

```
api_route = next(item for item in request.app.routes if isinstance(item, APIRoute) and item.dependant.cache_key[0] == request.scope['endpoint'])
```